# Return model with data annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model, .net-core

I want to return a model from my web api( net core) with all the data annotation info.
Example:

```
public class MyModel{
[Required]
string name;
int age;
}
```

Should return something like this:

```
{
    "name":"exampleName",
    "age": 19
},
[
{
    "property":"name",
    "type":"string",
    "required":true
},
{
    "property":"age",
    "type":"int",
    "required":false
}
]
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Or something in the net Core framework that already something like this?

Comment: Why? that's wrong ... those declarative validation is only for your Api to understand and not your Api consumer.

Comment: search for swagger for .net

Comment: as @Selvin pointed out just use Swagger.net

Comment: I want to use this for code generation in my frontend. @Selvin can swagger modify my model to return something like this?